# If output of bash command is empty, do something

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Hi I am new to bash so please excuse me if I have a really silly/easy question. I am writing a script which allows the user to change their region (for wireless). What I am wanting to do is put a check in place, so if they type in an incorrect value, it brings up the prompt again to input the region. I want to do this by checking if the output of the command `sudo iw reg set $reg`, if it is a correct input, there is no output. But if it is a wrong input, it gives an error message.  I tried to do this but im getting an error:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please set a region: " 
read reg

if [(sudo iw reg set $reg) -ne 0]; then
    echo "Please set a valid region: "  
    read reg

else    
    echo "Setting reg as $reg"
    sudo iw reg set $reg 
fi
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `-z` test, type `help test` in Bash to learn more (`test` is the same as the `[` command).

You should only call `iw reg set` once, unless it fails.

```
echo "Please set a region: "

while true # infinite loop
do

    # read in the region:
    read reg

    # try the command, and catch its output:
    output=$( sudo iw reg set "$reg" 2>&1 )

    if [ -z "$output" ]
    then
        # output is empty - success - leave the loop:
        break
    else
        # output is non-empty - continue:
        echo "Please set a valid region. "
    fi

done
```

This snippet checks the success condition you gave in your question (empty output), but it should be noted that usually exit codes should be used if possible.

Note the `2>&1` operator redirecting stderr to stdout so any output on either file descriptor will be considered a failure.

Comment: This 15+ line script is exactly same as what I had earlier posted in 3 lines.

Comment: Oh mo, not talking about copying. I am saying programmatically same code

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, I figured a little extra verbosity could help the OP.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `read` in a `while` loop:

```
while read -r -p "Please set a valid region: " reg; do    
   [[ -z "$(sudo iw reg set $reg)" ]] && break
done
```

`help read` gives this:

- `-r`  do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
- `-p prompt`   output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
          attempting to read
- `$(...)` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to execute a command and return output
- `-z` returns `true` when given string argument  (output of `iw` command) is empty